# (javascript) JSON.parse() changes content of json

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, parsing

I'm making a practice tool for a game that helps you to learn how to play songs with the piano and what i'm trying to is get all the notes that are pressed within 50ms from one another and make them display as "you have to press them together" 
now, this seems to be working but when i pass the string of the song to the parser, it changes the content of the array. i've used the exact same method to parse the object in other functions and it works as expected, here not, this is (part) of the unparsed array

```
[{"time":2937,"key":"Key2"},
{"time":2943,"key":"Key7"},
{"time":2949,"key":"Key0"},
{"time":4297,"key":"Key6"},
{"time":4306,"key":"Key11"},
{"time":4315,"key":"Key2"},
{"time":5547,"key":"Key5"},
{"time":5549,"key":"Key2"},
{"time":5554,"key":"Key7"},
{"time":7480,"key":"Key8"},
{"time":7814,"key":"Key9"},
```

this is after being parsed

```
0: {time: 2943, key: "Key7"}
1: {time: 4297, key: "Key6"}
2: {time: 4306, key: "Key11"}
3: {time: 4315, key: "Key2"}
4: {time: 5547, key: "Key5"}
5: {time: 5549, key: "Key2"}
6: {time: 5554, key: "Key7"}
7: {time: 7480, key: "Key8"}
8: {time: 7814, key: "Key9"}
9: {time: 8158, key: "Key5"}
10: {time: 8166, key: "Key10"}
```

why does this happen and how can i fix it?
the code is litterally:

```
console.log(song)
trainingSong = JSON.parse(song)
console.log(trainingSong)
```

Comment: There's something wrong with the code snippet - JSON.parse() expects a string, while you pass it an array. You can call JSON.stringify() on song before passing it to JSON.parse()

Comment: the first is a string not an array, it's the innerHTML of a div used to hold the song notes

Comment: JSON.parse will not reorder the array. Something else must be. You need to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.stringify` to stringify the code & then use `JSON.parse` to parse it.

```js
console.log(
  JSON.stringify([
    { time: 2937, key: "Key2" },
    { time: 2943, key: "Key7" },
    { time: 2949, key: "Key0" },
    { time: 4297, key: "Key6" },
    { time: 4306, key: "Key11" },
    { time: 4315, key: "Key2" },
    { time: 5547, key: "Key5" },
    { time: 5549, key: "Key2" },
    { time: 5554, key: "Key7" },
    { time: 7480, key: "Key8" },
    { time: 7814, key: "Key9" },
  ])
);
```

Comment: i tried with this:

console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(song)))
console.log(typeof(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(song))))
and the result is the same as if it wasnt parsed and type of is string

Comment: @Specy you have to stringify it first since you have an array as Omer said in the comment. once you do that, this should work :)

Comment: I think you've missed the point of the question (it really isn't expressed clearly, I also thought it was about `console.log` expressing the data differently at first). The input and output have the objects in the array in different orders.

Comment: @Quentin oh yeah i saw that now but the question was about parsing JSON, no? OP has the algo for different orders i guess

Comment: @Quentin look here https://pastebin.com/7N8bxpX7
the array is ordered (you can see the time growing) but the keys are wrong and time is not the same as unparsed array.
i'll delete this post and make another if it's not clear enough

Comment: @Specy — JSON.parse won't do that. You need to provide a [mcve] (in the question itself, SO does support life demos).

Comment: @Quentin is right. This has nothing to do with JSON.